# Out of office in outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Clearly the geeks at microsoft have decided that a simple out of office with the option to configure in advance (as in Outlook 2007) should be replaced with an unecessarily complex and less flexible out of office options.

Typing the out of office message and adding the date and time you want it to run from was a simple and effective tool. Now if you want to set a date in advance you have to go into rules, advanced and set the date (not a time as that option has gone) create a template etc etc. A big step back. Anyone know of an add-in that brings back the functionality of earlier outlook versions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without any add-in, just add **automatic replies...** command to the **Quick Access toolbar**:

- open drop-down menu of `Quick Access Toolbar`
- select `more commands`
- for "choose commands from" select `File Tab`
- Select `Automatic replies...`
- Click `Add >>`
- Click `OK`

Now you can set out office message just by a click, or pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + corresponding number.

Comment: You can also access this option by clicking `File` -> `Automatic Replies`